# Alternative solutions to $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{ 1/{\sqrt{n}}}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Here is a limit that can be computed directly by performing the integration and then taking
the limit, but the way is rather ugly. What else can we do? Might we avoid the integration? 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{ 1/{\sqrt{n}}}^{1}\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}\mathrm{d}x$$

Comment: Where do you get this stuff from?

Comment: @GitGud: from my brother and some pals.

Comment: Have you tried l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @Bruno: ah, good idea! Thanks.

Comment: @downvoter: what's the reason of the downvote?

Comment: Downvote?  Who knows?  Maybe stating a problem with no effort shown to solve it.

Comment: @GEdgar: Did you read the text? I just wrote that I know a way that is rather ugly...

Comment: @Gigili: what are you doing kid? Don't modify my posts, OK?

Comment: JFYI, salutations and signatures must be removed from posts. Refer to [Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) for more information. Please try to be more polite, this is not your personal website.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures

Comment: @robjohn: I'll remove them.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals: See the FAQ: [If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#editing).

Comment: @ZevChonoles: THIS IS MY LAST POST. PLEASE REMOVE MY USER.

Comment: Chris's sister: your contributions here are very worthwhile. I have enjoyed following your questions and answers for a while now. Please don't rage-quit.

Comment: I believe every single user in this site aims to know more about Maths, instead of arguing. Please stay calm and rational.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals For every complainer there are probably 20 people like me who really like your posts; they just don't speak up and say so.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals, you are great if you have a problem with the site let's discuss it on meta. It would be really a shame to lose you.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals, Please don't go. Your questions are much appreciated.

Comment: Chris's sis: I would like to see more of your questions! :) They are really fun! Looks like this is one of the last ones you have asked in a while :(

Comment: @Prism I will never be a active again on main. People that hit me didn't understand that I didn't care of points, but only of math. They will never have me here again. But ... I'm active in chat, and I try to post there some beautiful questions! :-)

Comment: That's such a pity! Ah I wish you wouldn't say "never" :( but okay, maybe sometime I will drop in chat to see what questions you have posted there :)

Comment: @Prism thank you for your appreciation. Such people are very rare. :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An alternate way is to notice that expanding the integrand also gives:

$$\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}<\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}< \frac{1}{x^2}\;\,\text{for}\;\,0<x<1$$

Hence:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^1\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x}\,dx< \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}dx< \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^1\frac{1}{x^2}dx$$

$$1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{\ln\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}dx< 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{1/\sqrt{n}}^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}\to 1$$

Comment: That's a very nice way.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

By L`Hopital's rule:

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} -\frac{\ln(1 + \sqrt{n}) n^{1.5} \frac{-1}{2 n^{1.5}}}{0.5 n^{-0.5}}$$
$$ = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \ln(1 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}) \sqrt{n}$$
Using the fact that
$$\ln(1 + x) = x + O(x^2)$$

We see that the limit is $1$.

Comment: Thanks (+1). I think we should also tell a word about the behaviour of the numerator before applying L`Hopital's rule.

Comment: Perhaps, as $x\rightarrow 0$, that integral strongly resembles that of $\int \frac{1}{x^2}$.

Comment: @Chris'ssisterandpals it's only required that the denominator tend to $\infty$ to apply L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Ah, didn't know that, thank you antonio.

Answer (score 5):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}\mathrm dx=\lim _{t\to \infty}\frac{1}{t}\int_{\frac{1}{t}}^1\dfrac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}\mathrm dx= \lim _{t\to \infty}\ln(1+t^{-1})t^3/t^2=1$$ By l'Hospital's rule and $\log(1+x)/x\to1$

Answer (score 5):

Not strictly avoiding the integration, but expanding the integrand makes it pretty straightforward:

$$\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x^3}=\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{x}{4}+\cdots$$

$$\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1 \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x^3}dx=\left[-\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\ln x}{2}+\frac{x}{3}-\cdots\right]_{1/\sqrt{n}}^1=-\frac{3}{4}+\sqrt{n}+\frac{\ln \sqrt{n}}{2}-\frac{1}{3\sqrt{n}}+\cdots$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1 \frac{\ln (1+x)}{x^3}dx=1-\frac{3}{4\sqrt{n}}+\frac{\ln \sqrt{n}}{2\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{3n}+\cdots\to 1$$

Comment: That was pretty fast. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Close to $x = 0$, we have
$$\frac{\log(1+x)}{x^3} \sim \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{2x} + \cdots$$
Pick a $\delta > 0$ such that the error term in R.H.S is $O(1)$ on $(0,\delta)$, we have:

$$\begin{align} \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x^3} dx 
&= \left(\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^\delta + \int_{\delta}^1\right) \frac{\log(1+x)}{x^3} dx\\
&= \left[ -\frac{1}{x} -\frac12 \log x \right]_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^\delta + O(\delta) + \int_{\delta}^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x^3} dx\\
&= \sqrt{n} +\frac12 \log ( \sqrt{n} ) + O(\frac{1}{\delta})
\end{align}$$
Notice $\delta$ has be chosen independent of $n$, we have:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1 \frac{\log(1+x)}{x^3} dx
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \left(\sqrt{n} +\frac12 \log ( \sqrt{n} ) + O(\frac{1}{\delta})\right) = 1$$

Comment: Thanks for your way (+1) Always rigorous.

Answer (score 2):

We have with the fact $x-\frac{x^2}{2}\leq\log(1+x)\leq x$,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{x^3}\leq\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1\frac{1}{x^2}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}({\sqrt{n}}-1)=1.$$
and
$$1=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(({\sqrt{n}}-1)-\frac{1}{2}\log\sqrt{n})=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{2x}\leq\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}^1\frac{\log(1+x)}{x^3}$$
We can conclude.

Comment: There's a mistake in your integration.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over \root{n}}
     \int_{ 1/\root{n}}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x^{3}}\,\dd x}$

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over \root{n}}%
> \int_{ 1/\root{n}}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} \over x^{3}}\,\dd x}}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over \root{n}}%
> \int_{ 1/\root{n}}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} - x + x^{2}/2 \over x^{3}}\,\dd x
> +{1 \over \root{n}}%
> \int_{ 1/\root{n}}^{1}{x - x^{2}/2 \over x^{3}}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over \root{n}}%
> \int_{ 1/\root{n}}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} - x + x^{2}/2 \over x^{3}}\,\dd x
> + 1 - {1 \over \root{n}} - {\ln\pars{n} \over 4\root{n}}}
> \\[3mm]&=1 + \lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{{1 \over \root{n}}%
> \int_{ 1/\root{n}}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 + x} - x + x^{2}/2 \over x^{3}}\,\dd x - {1 \over \root{n}} - {\ln\pars{n} \over 4\root{n}}}
> =\color{#00f}{\Large 1}
> \end{align}